# How can I make a stopwatch (timer) start from 00:00:00 after stopping and starting it again?

Tags: c#, timer, stopwatch

Soo I am making a stopwatch program, and I run into a little problem while making it stop and start.

This is the situation — I press "StartButton" and then I press "StopButton", but after pressing "StartButton" again, then it starts counting from the time it already counted.

The Timer function:

```
int i = 0;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i);
    textBox1.Text = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    i++;
}
```

The StopButton function:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button3.Visible = true;
    button4.Visible = false;
    timer1.Stop();
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    textBox1.Text = "00:00:00";
}
```

The StartButton function:

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button4.Visible = true;
    button3.Visible = false;
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    timer1.Start();
        textBox1.Text = "00:00:00";
}
```

I've tried to just make the "textBox1" to write "00:00:00", but it does not work at all.

(PS I'm bad at C#).

Comment: what actually counts is `i`, reinit it to zero

Comment: Thank you, but i don't understand the downvotes, im just bad at programming and C#.

Answer (score 1):

I would also have added a field with a start value:

```
private DateTime _timeStart = DateTime.Now;
```

Starting / Restarting:

```
_timeStart = DateTime.Now; 
timer1.Start();
```

Displaying:

```
TimeSpan time = (DateTime.Now - _timeStart).TotalSeconds;
textBox1.Text ...
```

And... If you need to Pause the timer.

I would also have added and used these fields for handling the Paused time:

```
private DateTime _timePauseStart = DateTime.Now;
private TimeSpan _timeSpanPaused;
```

Begin Paused:

```
timer1.Stop();
_timePauseStart = DateTime.Now;
```

End Paused:

```
_timeSpanPaused += DateTime.Now - _timePauseStart;
timer1.Start();
```

Displaying:

```
TimeSpan time = (DateTime.Now - _timeStart - timeSpanPaused).TotalSeconds;
textBox1.Text ...
```

Comment: there is no timer1.reset or timer1.restart.

Comment: timer1.Stop();
            i = 0;
            TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i);
            textBox1.Text = time.ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm\:ss");

Answer (score 0):

I just understand your question. Timer start from 0 everytime you Stop and Start it.

Consider to use `Stopwatch` class. With Stopwatch you can always continue where it is paused.

In order to restart stopwatch, use

```
sw.Reset();
sw.Start();
```

or

```
sw.Restart();
```

To continue where you left, use

```
timer1.Stop();
timer1.Start();
```